# C# - Get ANSI code value of a character

Tags: character, ansi, windows-1252

I'd like to retrieve the ANSI code value of a given character.
E.g. when I now get the int value of the trademark character, I get 8482.
Instead I would like to get 153, which is the value of the trademark character in codepage 1252.

Some help would be appreciated.

Jurgen

Answer (score 3):

Found it myself:

```
Encoding ansiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
byte[] bytes = ansiEncoding.GetBytes(c);
int code = bytes[0];
```