# How to Split an ANSI string with unknown characters returned from OpenVMS in C#

Tags: c#, regex, split, ansi-escape, openvms

I have a method that I've written in C# that connects to OpenVMS, runs a command and then returns the output.

One of the DCL procedures it runs returns a "form" in the form of a string which has all sorts of ANSI encoding in it.

What I wish to do is to split the returned string into an array based on the ANSI escape character as a delimiter so that I can further sort it and build a display later on.

The problem i'm having is the escape character doesn't look like its being recognized. When I inspect the string in visual studio I can see the standard ANSI formatting with an arrow pointing left that looks like this: ← between each entry. This is the escape character.

If I paste the same string into notepad++ it shows up as ESC.

I've tried doing a split on the string with \033 being the delimiter, but that didn't work, I've also tried pasting the ESC character into a variable but it simply pastes an empty space.

So I'm wondering how do I find out what character code this escape character is using so that I can use it in my split.

Id post a screenshot but I don't have the rep to do that apparently.

edit: this is whats being returned:

```
[02;27HDIVIDEND SETUP       11:25   Mon, 21 Jul 2014[04;05HCurrent attach point : VOD_TIM[07;05H   Code     Description[07;60HDate       Run
```

Its not showing up as a character on StackOverflow but if you imagine the character is infront of each of the segments starting with a [

Edit 2: OKay se we've established that the int char code is 27 so the issue now is how do I use that in my split?

Comment: Can you please provide the code for the split?

Comment: Can you post your code? How do you get these strings - as byte array, as string, or what? And if you can determine where the problem character is located just get its number like `Int32 charCode = (Int32)str[problemCharIndex]` or do the same in the Watch window during the debugging `(Int32)str[problemCharIndex]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370812/c-sharp-get-ansi-code-value-of-a-character

Comment: The output is bring returned as a string from a Stream reader which is in a custom library called SSH.NET I shall try your code to see if I can get that character code

Comment: Hi Saj I tried that and I got an exception

Comment: What does `int i = (int)str[0];` provide in `i`?

Comment: OR  int i = (int)'x'; should return the ASCII code ?

Comment: You may have an ansi/Unicode issue too.  See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode8bit.html)

Comment: It comes back as int 27, so THorsten was right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out the splitting your string via [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8yttk7sy.aspx), something like this:

```
string input = YOUR_STRING_HERE;
string pattern = @"\033";

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
}
```

---

**Update:**

You can use the `\e` symbol for the `ESC` character in `Regex` in .Net, see the full list of escape characters in `Regex` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Comment: I think you must remove the `@` before the pattern string. Otherwise it will look for the literal sequence `\033` and not the character with code `033` or am I mistaken here?

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar In the documentation `@` persists, but I can't say for sure. I'll be appreciated if you can provide some additional info about this.

Comment: Actually ignore what I said it worked! I think the @ sign made the difference! Thanks VMAtm!